# Database design for a yearly updated database (once a year)

Tags: database, database-design

I have a large database which will only be updated once a year.  Every year of data will use the same schema (the data will not be adding any new variables).  There's a 'main' table where most of the customer information lives.  To keep track of what happens from year to year, is it better design to put a field in the main customer table that says what year it is, or have a 'year' table that relates to the main customer table?

Comment: What database will you be using? A portable DB? SQL Server, ORacle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend having a year field in the customer table, that way it is all together. You could even use a timestamp to automatically input the date of user sign up.

Answer (score 1):

To really answer, we'd need to see your schema, but it is almost never the right choice to make a new table for a new year. You probably want to relate years to customers.

Comment: I thought about having YEAR and then 2010, 2011, 2012 etc.  But I think things will be easier if I just make a field in the main table.

Comment: For a large database, having a different table per year is an easy way to do horizontal partitioning.

Comment: Is there some reason each customer needs something every year? Or is it just that each customer has some type of update each year that needs to be stored?

Comment: @Gabe For certain situations, definitely. Although he doesn't exactly sound like he's off building a high-performance data-warehouse.

Comment: @CollinHockey you're right :).  This is going to be used be me and just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would split off your archive data because you are doing OLTP stuff on your current data, because you want to mostly work on current data, and sometimes look at old stuff.  But you have very few updates it seems.  I guess the main driver is your queries, and what they 'usually' do, and what performance you need to get out of them.  Its probably easier for you to have everything in one table - with a year column.  But if most of your queries are for the current year, and they are tight on performance you may want to look at splitting the current data out - either using physical tables, or partitioning of the table (depending on the DB some can do this for you, whilst still being a single table)

Comment: In this situation we will be looking at older data just as often as the newer data, and comparing trends.

Comment: In which case its probably best to have it all in the same table I think